# Getter on onetomany relationship returning only a string (Symfony 4.10)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin

I am currently having an issue on my project.

I have two entities, one named Universe, the other named UniverseImage they have a oneToMany relation defined like such :

Inside the Universe Entity

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UniverseImage", mappedBy="universe")
 */
private $images;
```

Inside the UniverseImage Entity :

```
/**
 * @var Universe
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Universe", inversedBy="images")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="universe_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $universe;
```

My current issue is that when I call the getImages() method on a instance of a universe it returns me an array of strings which are the path of an image (an other property of the UniverseImage entity).

When I call the getter, it returns :

```
Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#1982
  ...
  #collection: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#1718 
    -elements: array:2 [
      0 => "Collection Women6.jpg"
      1 => "image6.jpg"
    ]
  }
  #initialized: true
}
```

Instead of returning an array of UniverseImage.

Do you have any ideas on how to do it ?
Thanks for the help :D

**-- EDIT --**

I noticed my problem might come from something I missconfigured in Sonata...

Inside configureFormFields I configured the Image field that way :

```php
            ->add(
                'images',
                CollectionType::class,
                array(
                    'label' => 'Images by exercices',
                ),
                array(
                    'edit' => 'inline',
                    'inline' => 'table',
                    'sortable' => 'position',
                    'link_parameters' => array('context' => 'prototype'),
                    'admin_code' => 'dior.admin.universeimage'
                )
            )
```

I need to add the __toString() method inside UniverseImage or else I will have an error because I have to display the entity.

Here are a part of the entity related to my problem :

The universe entity :

```php
/**
 * Universe
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="universe")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Admin\UniverseRepository")
 */
class Universe
{
...
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UniverseImage", mappedBy="universe")
     */
    private $images;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name . "";
    }

...
  /**
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection|UniverseImage[]
     */
    public function getImages(): \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $images
     * @return void
     */
    public function setImages(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $images): self
    {
        $this->images = $images;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addImage(UniverseImage $image): self
    {
        if (!$this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->images[] = $image;
            $image->setUniverse($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeImage(UniverseImage $image): self
    {
        if ($this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->images->removeElement($image);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($image->getUniverse() === $this) {
                $image->setUniverse(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The universeImage entity:

```php
/**
 * UniverseImage
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="universe_image", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_403241E5CD9AF2", columns={"universe_id"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_403241E89D40298", columns={"exercice_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Admin\UniverImageRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @Vich\Uploadable()
 */
class UniverseImage
{

...

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $path;


    /**
     * @var Universe
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Universe", inversedBy="images")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="universe_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     */
    private $universe;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->path . "";
    }

    public function getUniverse(): ?Universe
    {
        return $this->universe;
    }

    public function setUniverse(?Universe $universe): self
    {
        $this->universe = $universe;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you retrieve the entities from db with custom db queries?

Comment: I don't. I use it inside the SonataAdmin Bundle and it seems like the Universe is stored in the current session. So maybe in the background they do retrieve it with custom queries

Comment: the getter does nothing but `return $this->images`?

Comment: Yes, that's the only thing it does. From some research I made, the issue might be due to a function inside sonata. It uses a __toString() made inside the entity to store a part of the elements needed in the current session. But I am unable to find where it is stored...